# Get current time of a running CSS3 animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, dom-events

I am trying to get the current time of a running animation but I did not find anything. I can get the start time:

```
myelement.addEventListener('webkitAnimationStart', function (evt){ 
  console.log(evt.elapsedTime)                                   
});
```

and end time:

```
myelement.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function (evt){ 
  console.log(evt.elapsedTime)                                   
})
```

However I think that this is lame since those values are easy to get from the CSS.
Any ideas?

Comment: for finely-tuned animation, you should use JavaScript rather than CSS. CSS animations are meant as simple styling effects, not sustained user interactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS Animations have very limited state hooks. They do not report their current time (although you can get the currently applied transformation matrix by using window.getComputedStyle()).

You get a start and an end event - that's it. If you need to get current time, then use JavaScript.

Comment: Thanx Michael, that was my guess also. Gotta call a setInterval on Start. Lame...

Comment: This is no longer true thanks to the new Web Animation API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation/currentTime

Supported by default in FF and Chrome, partially supported in Safari, and there's a polyfill for IE.

Yay 2016